# using slider pro with full width and it overlaps the container

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have been trying to make my slider pro full width and it always overlaps the window size.

Here is the bootstrap nav code:

```
<!-- NAVIGATION -->
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
<div class="container-fluid">
<!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
<div class="navbar-header">
<button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse"    data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
  </button>
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
</div>

<!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li class="active"><a href="#">Link <span class="sr-only">(current)  </span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>

  </ul>
</div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
</div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>

<!-- / NAVIGATION -->
```

The slider pro html: (all default)

```
<div class="slider-div container">
<div>
<div id="example1" class="slider-pro">
<div class="sp-slides">
  <div class="sp-slide">
    <img class="sp-image" src="img/blank.gif"
      data-src="http://bqworks.com/slider-pro/images/image1_medium.jpg"
      data-retina="http://bqworks.com/slider-pro/images/image1_large.jpg"/>

<h1 class="sp-layer sp-white sp-padding" 
      data-horizontal="10" data-vertical="10" data-width="35%">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet <span class="hide-small-screen">, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</span> <span class="hide-medium-screen">Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</span>
</h1>

</div>

      <div class="sp-slide">
        <img class="sp-image" src="img/blank.gif"
          data-src="http://bqworks.com/slider-pro/images/image2_medium.jpg"
          data-retina="http://bqworks.com/slider-pro/images/image2_large.jpg"/>

    <h1 class="sp-layer sp-white sp-padding" 
      data-horizontal="10" data-vertical="10" data-width="35%">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet <span class="hide-small-screen">, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</span> <span class="hide-medium-screen">Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</span>
    </h1>

  </div>



</div>

<div class="sp-thumbnails">
  <div class="sp-thumbnail">
    <div class="sp-thumbnail-title">Lorem ipsum</div>
    <div class="sp-thumbnail-description">Dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit sed</div>
  </div>

  <div class="sp-thumbnail">
    <div class="sp-thumbnail-title">Do eiusmod</div>
    <div class="sp-thumbnail-description">Tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua</div>
  </div>


</div>

</div><!-- /slider pro -->
</div>  
</div><!-- /slider-div -->
```

I've changed nothing.

Here is the script:

```
<!-- SCRIPTS -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="libs/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="dist/js/jquery.sliderPro.min.js">   </script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$( document ).ready(function( $ ) {
$( '#example1' ).sliderPro({
  width: '100%',
  forceSize: 'fullWidth',
  height: 500,
  arrows: true,
  buttons: false,
  waitForLayers: true,
  thumbnailWidth: 150,
  thumbnailHeight: 100,
  thumbnailPointer: false,
  autoplay: false,
  fade: true,
  thumbnailArrows: true,
  fadeThumbnailArrows: true,
  autoScaleLayers: false,
  breakpoints: {
    500: {
      thumbnailWidth: 120,
      thumbnailHeight: 50
     }
    }
  });
 });
</script>
```

Here is the result:

[image showing sidebars](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gh7Wq.jpg)

I have been trying to fit it perfectly to the window size but if I add anything to my web page the side scroll appears even adding only divs with `h1`, `h2` and paragraph with no styles.

Comment: Your image doesn't work. Is this live somewhere or can you throw together a fiddle?

Comment: i fixed the image